# Xcode Swift: How to call UIPickerView from UIButton?

Tags: xcode, swift

I need to open UIPickerView once a user touch a UIButton and to return the text value choosen on UIPickerview to UIButton label.

I'm not able to change the UIButton'n inputview like for UITextField, so making the property writable seems to be the right way. Unfortunatelly nothing happens when the button is touched.

```
import UIKit

class ABButton: UIButton {

var modInputView: UIView!

override var inputView: UIView { get {

    if modInputView != nil {
        return modInputView
    }
    else {
        return super.inputView!
    }

}}

override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true

}
}


class LiczydloViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var buttonTempo10: ABButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var tempoPicker = UIDatePicker()


    buttonTempo10.modInputView = tempoPicker

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an action for touchUpInside for the button, and call button.becomeFirstResponder()

Answer (score 0):

try to set the frame of UIDatePicker. I tried it with luck.

```
class ZYInputButton: UIButton {
    var zyInputView: UIView?
    var zyInputAccessoryView: UIView?

    override var inputView: UIView? {
        get {
            return self.zyInputView
        }

        set {
            self.zyInputView = newValue
        }
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        get {
            return self.zyInputAccessoryView
        }

        set {
            self.zyInputAccessoryView = newValue
        }
    }

    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```